# Why are static members of template classes not unique

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, static-members

Take a look at the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    public:
    static T bar;
};

template <typename T> typename T Foo<T>::bar;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Foo<int>::bar : " << &Foo<int>::bar << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Foo<double>::bar : " << &Foo<double>::bar << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This will print out 2 different addresses. I can understand why in this case, `bar` is of type `T` and thus instantiations of different T's in `Foo<T>` will get you different static members. However, if we change `bar` to a type we already know ( e.g. `static int bar` ) this [still happens](http://ideone.com/xSsCMr).

Why is this the case? Why just not re-use `bar` for multiple template instantiations? How would I be able to get just 1 `bar` object throughout different instantiations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing really surprising going on here.

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    //...
};
```

Is not a class, it is a template to stamp out classes.  That means `Foo<A>` is a completely different class from `Foo<B>`.  As such all static members are unique to the *different* instantiated classes — and the fact that class template being same has no relevance in this context, as it is after all a template, the blueprint of the instantiated classes.

If you want all the different kinds of `Foo`'s to share a common state then you can have them inherit from the same base class and put the common information there.  Here is a very boiled down example:

```
struct Foo_Base
{
    static int bar;
};

int Foo_Base::bar = 10;

template<typename T>
struct Foo : Foo_Base {};

int main()
{   
    Foo<int> foo_i;
    Foo<double> foo_d;
    std::cout << foo_i.bar << "\n";
    foo_i.bar += 10;
    std::cout << foo_d.bar;
}
```

output:

```
10
20
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8fd54d19d46f551b)</kbd>

Comment: @Nawaz No problem.  I do question whether *and the fact that class template being same* should be *and the fact that the class template is the same*

Answer (score 9):

From the standard, $14.7/6 Template instantiation and specialization [temp.spec]

> Each class template specialization instantiated from a template has its own copy of any static members.

`Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` are irrelevant classes, even though they're instantiated from the same template, and they will have their own static member `bar`, even though their types are same (e.g. both `int`).

Comment: @NathanOliver I would assume "their types" refers to the types of the `bar` members; it could use a disambiguation, though.

Comment: Oh the member types.  I though you were talking about the class types.  never mind me then.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's fine. Anyway I tried to edit it to avoid disambiguation.

Comment: @songyuanyao Looks great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Foo<int>::bar` and `Foo<double>::bar` are two different global (statically accessible class-level) variables. they are not same. Consider this code:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    static T var1;
    static int var2;
};
```

What do you think the relative placement of `var2` be (assume compiler places `var2` just after `var1`)? In one case, it may be relatively just 1 byte ahead (`foo<char>`), but 8 bytes ahead in case of other datatype.