# Type-specific static declaration in a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I've just written the following snippet:

```
// Fix for MinGW 4.9.2 bug - std::log2 is missing there
template <typename T>
T log2 (T value)
{
    static const T l2 = std::log(T(2));
    return std::log(value) / l2;
}
```

Obviously, `l2` *should* be unique for each `T` type because it **is** of type `T`. But does it actually work that way as per the C++ standard?

Comment: did you try it? Why it should not work? each instantiation gets its own static variable

Comment: @tobi303: It struck me that in the nature of static declarations, it may be ONLY defined once (say, for whatever type instantiates it first). I can only try it with one compiler in the next couple days, but I'm actually writing cross-platform code here.

Comment: no, it is defined ONLY once FOR EACH instantiation of the template. I had a link to a nice video with an example on that, maybe I will find it...

Comment: here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXeu4fj3zOs) (around 6:00) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38059936/template-function-static-variable/38059959#38059959) is almost a dupe

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14663369/241631) answers your question, even though that question is about something unrelated.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345946/why-are-static-members-of-template-classes-not-unique.  It is for classes but it has the same behavior with functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that once instantiated

```
log2<double>
```

and

```
log2<float>
```

are two completely different functions. They both get their own `static` variable. After template instantiation, this is the same situation as if you had two functions:

```
double log2(double) {
    static double x;
    /*...*/
}
```

and

```
float log2(float) {
    static float x;
    /*...*/
}
```

This is also nicely explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXeu4fj3zOs) in an example around 6:00.